# Is there an alternative to GridFox?

Tags: firefox, layout, firefox-addon

I've been using the very handy Firefox plugin "GridFox" for some time now, to overlay grids on my own web page designs but also on other sites as a way of identifying how they have done their layout. But since Firefox 45 GridFox has stopped working for me, all it gives a uniform grey wash across the screen and no matter what configuration I put in, no columns appear. I've updated the plugin, and tried writing to the author (no reply), and looked all over for an alternative, without success. I can't use Chrome (security restrictions on Chrome plugins here for some reason), so it has to be Firefox.

Comment: To add: I went back to v37 on Ubuntu and it works fine - however there is another problem with Gridfox which has already been noted elsewhere, which is that the maximum screen width is 1024px, hardly adequate with a lot of today's sites (notably mine which uses Bootstrap > 1200px)

Comment: Your above comment should be included in the question text. Please [edit] your question to include it.  Basically, all information which is relevant to answering the question should be in the Question, not only in comments.  Comments are generally considered to be transitory.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: well, since SO is for *software-development-related questions*, i suggest you download the XPI, unpack it (it contains the source) and try to debug the issue. Then if you have further questions about debugging you can ask them here.